# Castle Windsor: How to prevent circular references in factory-created objects were the created objects refers back to the factory

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, factory

I am using windsor castle as my IoC container, and has run in to a bit of a problem. This is best explained in code, so I´ll give it a try.
I have a factory class, that should provide me with implementations of a certain interface:

```
public interface IObjectCreatorFactory
{
    IObjectCreator GetObjectCreator(Type objectType);
}
public interface IObjectCreator
{
    T CreateObject<T>(IDataRow data);
    bool SupportsType(Type type);
}
```

Implementation of the factory class could look like this, though I am not sure this is the way to go:
    public interface ObjectCreatorFactory:IObjectCreatorFactory
    {
        IEnumerable specificCreators;
        IObjectCreator defaultCreator;

```
    public ObjectCreatorFactory(IEnumerable<IObjectCreator> specificCreators, IObjectCreator defaultCreator)
    {
        this.specificCreators= specificCreators;
        this.defaultCreator= defaultCreator;
    }
    public IObjectCreator GetObjectCreator(Type objectType)
    {
        foreach (IObjectCreator creator in specificCreators)
        {
            if (creator.SupportsType(objectType))
            {
                return creator;
            }
        }
        return defaultCreator;
    }
}
```

Now this would work out ok, but if I want my IObjectCreator instance to create child objects using a specific IObjectCreator, i would like to call ObjectCreatorFactory, and this obviously results in a circular reference:

```
public void SpecificObjectCreator:IObjectCreator
{
    IObjectCreatorFactory objCreatorFactory;
    public SpecificObjectCreator(IObjectCreatorFactory objCreatorFactory)
    {
        this.objCreatorFactory = objCreatorFactory;
    }
    T CreateObject<T>(IDataRow data)
    {
        T obj = new T;
        ChildObject childObject = objCreatorFactory.GetObjectCreator(typeof(ChildObject)).CreateObject<ChildObject>(data);
         .......
    }
    bool SupportsType(Type type);        
}
```

This does not work out. What would be the way to go for this scenario, where the created objects are refering back to the factory for child object creators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply move the factory out of the constructors of the various specific object creators, and introduce a method on the IObjectCreator interface instead, responsible for initialising the creators:

```
public interface IObjectCreator
{
    T CreateObject<T>(IDataRow data);
    bool SupportsType(Type type);
    void Initialize(IObjectCreatorFactory factory);
}
```

And then just invoke Initialze(this) on each object creator passed into the factory.

In the past I've used custom life cycle stages to take care of automatically invoking "post-construction" setup of components to both avoid circular dependencies and also to take care of other associated concerns (i.e. applying additional component configuration from an external source like a database) - but it's probably overkill for what you need.

Comment: This is an ok way to go. I ended up replacing my factory class with a locator class. The class then locates Creators by using windsorContainer.Resolve(constructorName).